# C++ Generic Callback class with removable listeners by unique id

Tags: c++, generics, template-meta-programming, callback

I'm quite new to the STL.

Does this make sense? Is there a better way of removing the listeners instead of using shared_ptr while keeping the code short and simple? Is there something in the STL to replace this?

Class:

```
template<class ... Arguments>
class Callback
{
    using Function = std::function<void(Arguments ...)>;
    using FunctionPtr = std::shared_ptr<Function>;
    using Functions = std::vector<FunctionPtr>;

public:
    FunctionPtr addListener(Function f) {
        FunctionPtr fp = std::make_shared<Function>(f);
        _functions.push_back(fp);
        return fp;
    }

    void removeListener(FunctionPtr fp){
        _functions.erase(std::find(_functions.begin(), _functions.end(), fp));
    }

    void operator()(Arguments ... args) const{
        for (auto & f : _functions)
            f.get()->operator()( args ... );
    }

private:
    Functions _functions;
};
```

Use case:

```
int main()
{
    Callback<int> callback;

    callback.addListener([](int i){
        std::cout << "Listener 1 -> Input is " << i <<  std::endl;
    });

    auto id = callback.addListener([](int i){
        std::cout << "Listener 2 -> Input is " << i <<  std::endl;
    });

    callback.addListener([](int i){
        std::cout << "Listener 3 -> Input is " << i <<  std::endl;
    });

    callback.removeListener(id);

    callback(71);
}
```

Output is:

```
Listener 1 -> Input is 71
Listener 3 -> Input is 71
```

**Addendum**
One limitation of this approach is that you can't remove or add listeners inside the callback functions since it would break the iteration. What I found is that this limitation is especially annoying when you want something to only trigger once and then be removed.
The easiest solution I found is to simply have a separate list of callbacks that are called once and then removed automatically after the iteration.
Another easy, more generic solution is to copy the listeners container before triggering the callbacks with the obvious performance cost.

Comment: If you are the only person with a pointer to an object why do you need a "shared pointer" just use "unique pointer" it would be more efficient. Why dynamically create a pointer when you can simply store the "Function" in the vector?

Comment: The shared:ptr is there just to provide  an unique id to the std::function although as suggested in the answer below it is probably better to return a weak:ptr. I'm not sure if an iterator would also work because I think removing an object from the collection will invalidate it.

Comment: You could use a container were removing elements does not invalidate existing iterators.  But I don't like the idea of iterators either as it gives the user of your class an opportunity to abuse the system (they can call the stored function via the iterator). So I would do some extra work to make the iterator opaque. Or keep track via some index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's quite OK like that. Of course that depends on the use case and your goal.

One thing I would definitely change though is to return only a `std::weak_ptr` from `addListener`.

Here a few alternative approaches:
replace the `std::vector` with

- a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` and keep the `std::weak_ptr` as the "ID", or
- a `std::list` and use the `iterator` as "ID", or
- a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` and make up your own ID, maybe just as simple as a static integer counter.

Those all make the removal faster (logarithmic or constant instead of linear). The addition is already and would stay constant (at least amortized).

Also if you want the returned "ID" to be a little more "ID-like" and don't want to use a map you could wrap the `std::weak_ptr` or the `std::list::iterator` into an `Id` class. And if you then want the single member of the `Id` class to not be accessable by the user make it private and `Callback` a `friend`.

---

Further non question related remarks:

Adding the missing header would have been a good polish for the otherwise good and complete question to make it truly copy&paste&runnable.

You could add a few `const`/references here and there:

- `addListener` argument can be `const&&`
- `removeListener` argument can be `const&`
- `operator()` arguments can be `const&`
- the `f` in the `for` loop could also be `const`

although it will not always help that much.

Comment: Btw I got the perception that you just want to return an ID from your example use case. If you of course want to actually use the inserted and returned function (pointer) then my answer is a whole lot of gibberish of course.

Comment: Yes, the shared_ptr is intended to be used just as an ID so your answer is spot on. I could have made it clearer in the question.

Answer (score 3):

I think this makes sense in terms of STL use.  Storing a `std::shared_ptr<std::function>` is not usually necessary since std::function may own heap allocations internally, but since you return the shared_ptr from addListener it could be passed around.  If you never use the returned shared_ptr, you could just store a `std::vector<std::function>` and return a handle for removal (maybe the handle could contain the index of the function in the vector?).

I can't say whether a vector of functions makes sense for your use case.  If you can avoid callbacks and call functions directly, that's definitely preferable -- makes optimization much easier for the compiler.

---

Other stuff:

```
class Callback
{
    using Function = std::function<void(Arguments ...)>;
```

These typedefs are nice, but could be better.  They should be public since they are used in the public API.  And perhaps the names could be clearer (e.g. `VecPtrFunc` instead of `Functions`)?

```
_functions.erase(std::find(_functions.begin(), _functions.end(), fp));
```

This seems OK, but if you call this a lot or if functions is big, this will be slow. You might prefer to use a data structure with sub linear lookup/delete like std::map or std::unordered_map.  Or you could use the index-handle idea above and remove from a vector more efficiently.

```
void operator()(Arguments ... args) const
```

If you were just calling one callee, this would be `Arguments&&` and you'd `std::forward` the args.  Since you use the `args...` in a loop, I guess this is fine.  Maybe `Arguments const&` is better in case folks pass in big types and don't want to copy?

Comment: Keep in mind that if the handle is the index in the vector than some handles might get invalidated on removal of another function.

Comment: that's a good point

Answer (score 1):

I used an `unordered_map<string, FunctionPtr>` because you can use `f.target_type().name()` as the ID. That way you can overload `removeListener` to either take the `Function` again or a string.

```
template <class... Arguments>
class Callback {
    using CallbackFunc = std::function<void(Arguments...)>;
    using CallbackFuncPtr = std::shared_ptr<CallbackFunc>;

   public:
    ~Callback() {
        _functions.clear();
    }

    std::string addListener(const CallbackFunc& f) {
        const std::string func = f.target_type().name();
        CallbackFuncPtr fp = std::make_shared<CallbackFunc>(f);
        _functions[func] = fp;
        return func;
    }

    bool removeListener(const CallbackFunc& f) {
        const std::string func = f.target_type().name();
        return removeListener(func);
    }

    bool removeListener(const std::string& func) {
        auto l = _functions.find(func);
        if (l != _functions.end()) {
            _functions.erase(l);
            return true;
        } else {
            std::cerr << "Callback::removeListener(): listener not found" << std::endl;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void operator()(Arguments... args) const {
        for (const auto& [key, value] : _functions) {
            value.get()->operator()(args...);
        }
    }

   private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, CallbackFuncPtr> _functions;
};
```